# Using XPATH how to find a text and click on button

Tags: javascript, xpath, nightwatch.js

Bellow is my elements:

[image: Elements]

I already know how can I find the `id='0'` using:

```
.waitForElementVisible("//form[contains(@id, '0')]").
```

My current problem is how to identify "Excelente Contribuição in "<form". I need to click on text Excelente contruibuição.

I try to use this one to identify the element first, but don't work:

```
.waitForElementVisible("//form[contains(@id, '0') and contains(text()='Excelente contribuição')]")
```

Bellow is the button I need to click.

[image: My button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this XPath to match `form` by `@id` and `div` by `label` text:

```
//form[@id='0']//div[label[normalize-space()='Excelente contribuição']]
```

Comment: Cool! it's work. One question if possible you explain for me. If I want to click on all 'Excelente contribuição' I have in the id='0' is it possible? for example if I have two identical texts.

Comment: @JuanCarlos not exactly understand... You have two labels with the same text inside forms with different `@id`?

Comment: I have one id and two radio groups, in each radio group I have the same answers, in this case I have 2 'Excelente Contribuição'

Comment: @JuanCarlos in this case if you want to select the second one you can try `//form[@id='0']//div[label[normalize-space()='Excelente contribuição'] and position()=2]`